# Consolidating multiple Python Charts into one Dashboard with Plotly-Dash

Tags: callback, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I have two different Python Dashboards, both of which visualize different types of financial data. I would like to have both figures on one single dashboard, one above the other. Would you happen to know if that is possible? If so, I'm sure one has to extend the entire app structure, including the layout and, more importantly, callback part. Has anyone any experience with merging two apps into one dashboard? Below you'll find my code I've assembled so far.

First Dashboard:

```
# import relevant packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import plotly
import dash
import pyodbc

import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

data = [['2020-01-31', 100, 100, 100], ['2020-02-28', 101, 107, 99], ['2020-03-31', 104, 109, 93], ['2020-04-30', 112, 115, 94], ['2020-05-31', 112, 120, 89]]
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['DATE', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
df = df.set_index('DATE')
df

# create the Dash app
app = dash.Dash()

# Set up the app layout
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Index Dashboard'),
    html.P('''Pick one or more stocks from the dropdown below.'''),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='index-dropdown',
                options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                        for x in df.columns],
                value='A',
                multi=True, clearable=True),
    dcc.Graph(id='price-graph')
])


# Set up the callback function
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='price-graph', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='index-dropdown', component_property='value')],
)

def display_time_series(selected_index):
    dff = df[selected_index] # Only columns selected in dropdown
    fig = px.line(dff, x=df.index, y=selected_index, labels={'x': 'x axis label'})

    fig.update_layout(
        title="Price Index Development",
        xaxis_title="Month",
        yaxis_title="Price",
        font=dict(size=13))

    return fig

# Run local server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Second Dashboard:

```
data2 = [['A', 'B', 0.4], ['A', 'C', 0.5], ['A', 'D', 0.1], ['X', 'Y', 0.15], ['X', 'Z', 0.85]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['BM_NAME', 'INDEX_NAME', 'WEIGHT'])
df2

barchart = px.bar(
    data_frame=df2,
    x=df2.BM_NAME,
    y="WEIGHT",
    color="INDEX_NAME",
    opacity=0.9,
    barmode='group')
barchart

# create the Dash app
app = dash.Dash()

# set up app layout
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='BM Composition'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='BM-dropdown',
                options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                        for x in df2.BM_NAME.unique()],
                 value='A',
                 multi=False, clearable=True),
    dcc.Graph(id='bar-chart')
])


# set up the callback function
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="bar-chart", component_property="figure"),
    [Input(component_id="BM-dropdown", component_property="value")],
)
def display_BM_composition(selected_BM):
    filtered_BM = df2[df2.BM_NAME == selected_BM]  # Only use unique values in column "BM_NAME" selected in dropdown

    barchart = px.bar(
        data_frame=filtered_BM,
        x="BM_NAME",
        y="WEIGHT",
        color="INDEX_NAME",
        opacity=0.9,
        barmode='group')

    return barchart

# Run local server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I don't understand what the problem is. If the end result should be a single app you could just put all layout and callback related code in a single dash app. Or is this question about keeping the code logically organized?

Comment: Exactly. Apologies, should've specified the question in more detail. Basically, I want these two dashboards combined in one single dash app. However, I find myself in a quandary insofar as I do not know how to best implement this, having multiple "dcc.Dropdown" elements and  "callbacks" at the same time.

Comment: The elements don't seem to conflict and you've said they should be shown on the same page so I don't see a problem with just putting everything together. But if you want to logically separate the parts then you can put each part in a separate file and initialize it in a main python script file that runs the combined app. The question and answer are different, but I think my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68467362/9098350) might contain useful parts for this question.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I didn't think that it would be that easy, just to combine everything. But it worked perfectly on my end. Python Dash is sometimes simpler than at first glance. Thanks Bas for your suggestion!